# Counting the number of self-avoiding rook paths for small grids

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-walk, integer-lattices

I was wondering if there's a formula or combinatorial method (perhaps by using induction or recursion) for counting the number of self-avoiding rook paths on a *m × n* grid for small values of m and n (for instance *m, n < 7*).

While studying smaller cases, I realized that you can simply prove by induction that for *2 × n* grids the number of these paths is 2^(n - 1) and there also seems to be a recursive function for grids of *3 × n* provided in [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html).

Comment: It seems like the link you provided has some information about the case $m = n$... Have you checked any of those references?

Comment: There are $4$ paths on a $2 \times 2$ grid.

Comment: @philbo_baggins; I have looked at the references, but I'm mostly interested in rectangles (i.e., m ≠ n)

Comment: @DanielMathias; I've arrived to the same conclusion and I'm looking for ways to extend it to larger grids for instance m, n = 3, 5.

Comment: Counting via code all possible paths of maximal length: $2\times n_{\ge 2} \implies \{4,8,14,22,32,44,58,\dots\}$ (an obvious pattern here) and $3\times n_{\ge 3} \implies \{20,62,132,336,688,1578,\dots\}$

Comment: @DanielMathias; Did you find any algorithm or pattern for counting the paths of 3 x n (maximal or not)?